# Google Play policy about Google Voice Typing (Google Search)

Tags: android, google-play

I'm making a voice recognition app using Google Voice Typing but I have a doubt about Google Voice Typing.
Is it against the policy if I write in my app that my app's voice recognizing precision depends on the precision of Google Voice Typing (which belongs to Google Search)? And I'm pretty sure that's the truth because I solely use SpeechRecognizer API without any tweaks to the recognizing mechanism.

Comment: Are you asking someone to read the policy for you, or you cannot find the policy to read it, or can't understand it, or what?

Comment: I guess it's about Intellectual Property part but they only say `Don’t infringe on the intellectual property rights of others, (including patent, trademark, trade secret, copyright, and other proprietary rights), or encourage or induce infringement of intellectual property rights.` and I have no idea about what's included in intellectual property rights.

Comment: Making a factual statement about your app's functionality would not infringe anyone's intellectual property rights.  Keep in mind I am a person you do not know posting on the internet, and if you need legal advice you should talk to a lawyer.  If you want to learn more on your own, internet searches for the various terms you quoted (patent, trademark, etc) should turn up some resources.

Comment: Many thanks for your information. About the lawyer thing, I don't think this is a serious enough business to takes one.

Comment: I agree, I just didn't want you to think you were getting real legal advice.